# How to List All Applications installed on a Mac using Python 2.7?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I need to get all the softwares installed on a Mac using Python. Is there is any module available? Or any dll kind of things that can be used?

In Windows I can get that info through these locations:

```
"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
"SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall"
```

Comment: Define "installed". An .app bundle lying around in a random directory counts as "installed" on Mac OS.

Comment: i am new mac os... In windows control panel you can find all installed programs right like that i need like that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use os module of python and execute find command

> find / -iname *.app

```
import os
output = os.popen("find / -iname *.app").read()
```